# What is the git command to erase all changes and revert to the state of your last commit?

Tags: git, github, command, reversion

I made a lot of unhelpful changes, and would like to revert to the state my repo was in before any of the changes.

Is there a git command for doing that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, to revert changes to tracked files:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

`git reset` alone resets the index; adding `--hard` resets the working copy as well. If you've already committed, specify a different commit to reset to - eg, `HEAD^` to revert to the parent commit of `HEAD` (ie, to remove the latest commit).

Next, to delete all untracked files:

```
git clean -dfx
```

`-d` tells it to delete directories, `-f` forces it to actually do the delete, and `-x` skips `.gitignore`d files.

Comment: After performing `git reset --hard HEAD` I'm still left with three of these `# modified:   vendor/plugins/human_attribute_override (modified content)`

Comment: In theory `--hard` ought to do it, but if that doesn't work, try `git checkout -f` as well.

Comment: Ah `git checkout -f` didn't not resolve those three little boogers either.

Comment: Interesting - are they read-only or something? `git reset --hard` should blow away any modified tracked files; if it doesn't, and there's no error, it's a bug. Try the git mailing list I guess...

Comment: Thanks Brother! I appreciate it. The three files in question are actually directories.. Strange.

Comment: Ahh! its because they are submodules.. not sure how to deal with those though.

Comment: @Trip, ah, I've not worked with submodules much, I'm afraid :/

Comment: Each submodule is its own repo, you'll have to work with them individually the same way or wipe them out and redo the `git submodule init` stuff.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly you have committed something and want it reverted `git reset --hard HEAD^`

If you haven't committed anything and it's only your working tree that is messed up then `git reset --hard HEAD`